# How to check if list1 contains some elements of list2?

Tags: python, list

I need to remove few strings from the list1 so i put them into list2 and just cant find out how to make it works.

```
list1 = ['abc', 'def', '123']
list2 = ['def', 'xyz', 'abc']  # stuff to delete from list1
```

And I would like to remove 'abc' and 'def' from list1 so it only contains things that i need

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using list comprehension as a filter, like this

```
set2, list1 = set(['def', 'xyz', 'abc']), ['abc', 'def', '123']
print [item for item in list1 if item not in set2]
# ['123']
```

We convert the elements of `list2` to a set, because they offer faster lookups.

The logic is similar to writing like this

```
result = []
for item in list1:
    if item not in set2:
        result.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any duplicate in `list1` (or if you want to remove duplicates), you can use this:

```
list1 = set(['abc', 'def', '123'])
list2 = set(['def', 'xyz', 'abc'])
print(list(list1 - list2))
```

Comment: It will fail for `list1, list2 = ['1', '1', '2'], ['2']`

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = set(['abc', 'def', '123'])
list2 = set(['def', 'xyz', 'abc'])

# here result will contain only the intersected element
# so its very less.

result = set(filter(set(list1).__contains__, list2))
newlist = list()

for elm in list1:
    if elm not in result:
        newlist.append(elm)
print newlist
```

Output:

```
['123']
```

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter answer using [builtin set methods](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
list1 = ['abc', 'def', '123']
list2 = ['def', 'xyz', 'abc']
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
print(set1.difference(set2)))
```

Quote from above documentation:

> "Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others."